# Yodlee: how to refresh expired cobrand access

Tags: yodlee

i've registered with Yodlee developer site and got 45 day access to testing API. Now my access expired and i would like to refresh my access without need to re-register with another email address. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem . You can get in touch with the **Yodlee sales team** and provide your username( which you had used to log in to the developer portal).

You can also provide your details in the LiveChat which you will find on the bottom right hand corner(in Yodlee Developer Portal) with a label - "**Leave a message**"

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik